# how to get all possible combinations when both a symbol and set of symbols could have different values

Tags: python, combinations

For example, we have the next string:

`string = 'abcd'`

And need to get all possible combinations if:

```
'a' = 1
'b' = 2
'c' = 3
'd' = 4
'ab' = 5
'cd' = 6
'abc' = 7
```

So the result should be:

```
'1234', '534', '56', '126', '74'
```

Should be done in Python

Comment: You forgot to post the Python code you wrote to try and solve this.

Comment: Can you be more clear with sample input and code?

Comment: sorry, but I have no ideas

Comment: What's the result? What does it represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiY6_HEjfDpAhUFg3IEHXeBDtYQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fitertools.html&usg=AOvVaw2YKU-g2HKgyZZIrgRqchXX) to do this:

```
from itertools import permutations

strings = ['a','b','c','d','ab','cd','abc']
all_combin = [s for i in range(2,len(strings)+1) for s in permutations(strings,i)] # List of all possible combinations of letters from the list
num = []
for n in all_combin:
    if ''.join(n) == 'abcd':
        a = ''
        for l in n:
            a += str(strings.index(l)+1)
        num.append(a)
print(num)
```

Output:

['56', '74', '126', '534', '1234']

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you would want to make a list, then create a for loop to go through each iteration. If you are looking for them in order, for the number in the hundredth position, take 3-1(you could find how many for loops you went through) and times it by 10 that many times. Finally to check if you have gotten that number before, have a for loop that goes through a list that is storing the results, check if it matches it, some thing like `for x in your_list`

I hope this helps